# How to merge column output to the end of a row in the previous column?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a .csv file containing three columns and I need to merge the value of column 2 with the end of the row of column 1.

The .csv file contains thousands of rows and this needs to be done for each row.

Iv'e tried using awk but I'm finding it difficult to get the code correct

```
cat file.csv | awk '{print $1, $2}' 

awk '{if ($2!= " ") {print $1+$2 }}'

These of course don't work
```

Sample input:

The command used to produce the actual output is simply:
    cat test.csv

```
[2,4,5,6,2,34,61,32,34,54,34,       22]     0.144354
[3,4,6,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,53,23,       34]     0.332453
[2,43,6,2,1,2,5,8,9,0,8,6,34,       21]     0.347643
```

Desired Output:

```
             col1                       col2
[2,4,5,6,2,34,61,32,34,54,34,22]     0.144354
[3,4,6,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,53,23,34]     0.332453
[2,43,6,2,1,2,5,8,9,0,8,6,34,21]     0.347643
```

Comment: `sed 's/  *//' file`?`There are two spaces before *.

Comment: You showed us actual output and desired output but you forgot to show us the associated input. Some of the answers are assuming that by "csv" you mean comma-separated while others are assuming the "c" means "character" rather than "comma" and assuming that character is a space. So - [edit] your question to show the input that produces the output you posted from the commands you posted so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it to show the actual input and desired output. By "csv" I mean comma - separated.

Comment: So `Actual output` is actually the `Sample input`? You could make that a bit clearer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace "comma followed by one or more spaces" with "comma":

```
sed 's/, \{1,\}/,/' file.csv
sed 's/, */,/g' file.csv
```

Print columns $1 and $2 as $1 (optionally separate with a tab):

```
awk '{print $1 $2, $3}' OFS='\t' file.csv
```

Comment: @EdMorton How do you match one or more occurrences with POSIX sed?

Comment: Use the RE interval `\{1,\}` instead of `\+` (and similarly `\{0,1\}` instead of `\?`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
awk '{printf("%s%s\t%s\n",$1,$2,$3)}' file.cvs
```

Answer (score 0):

I only see spaces after a comma when you don't want them.

```
$: sed -E 's/,\s+/,/' file.csv
[2,4,5,6,2,34,61,32,34,54,34,22]     0.144354
[3,4,6,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,53,23,34]     0.332453
[2,43,6,2,1,2,5,8,9,0,8,6,34,21]     0.347643
```

Add `-i` (*after* the `-E`) to make it an in-place edit.

```
$: sed -Ei 's/,\s+/,/' file.csv
$: cat file.csv
[2,4,5,6,2,34,61,32,34,54,34,22]     0.144354
[3,4,6,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,53,23,34]     0.332453
[2,43,6,2,1,2,5,8,9,0,8,6,34,21]     0.347643
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sed for `\s` and that syntax of `-i` and GNU or OSX/BSD sed for `-E`.